# Bootstrap PHP contact form

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, contact-form, unify

I had faced a problem with bootstrap PHP contact form .
I using Unify theme bootstrap framework , UI is done but I wouldn't know how to make contact form function . Can anyone help and make correction for me . 
here my website . http://cloudsblack.info/

**HTML PART .**

```
    <!-- Contact Section -->
<section id="contact" class="contacts-section">
    <div class="container content-lg">
        <div class="title-v1">
            <h2>Contact Us</h2>
            <p>I'm always happy to hear from you. Please contact or email me for appointment or service enquiry.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="row contacts-in">
            <div class="col-md-6 md-margin-bottom-40">
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Kuala Lumpur</li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> (6)016-7187764</li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> <a href="1122johnho@gmail.com">1122johnho@gmail.com</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                 <form method="post" action="index.php">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <div class="row margin-bottom-20">
                        <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-0">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        </div>                
                    </div>

                    <label>Email<span class="color-red">*</span></label>
                    <div class="row margin-bottom-20">
                        <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-0">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        </div>                
                    </div>

                    <label>City</label>
                    <div class="row margin-bottom-20">
                        <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-0">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        </div>                
                    </div>

                    <label>Telephone</label>
                    <div class="row margin-bottom-20">
                        <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-0">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        </div>                
                    </div>


                    <label>Interested</label>
                    <div class="row margin-bottom-20">
                        <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-0">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        </div>                
                    </div>

                    <label>Message</label>
                    <div class="row margin-bottom-20">
                        <div class="col-md-11 col-md-offset-0">
                            <textarea rows="8" class="form-control"></textarea>
                        </div>                
                    </div>

                    <p><button type="submit" class="btn-u btn-brd btn-brd-hover btn-u-dark">Send Message</button></p>
                </form> 
            </div>
        </div>            
    </div>
```

**AND here is PHP part .**

```
<?php
$Name = $_POST['name'];
$Email = $_POST['email'];
$City = $_POST['city'];
$Telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$Interested = $_POST['interested'];
$Message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: Johnhophotography.com'; 
$to = 'cloudsblack84@gmail.com'; 
$subject = 'Message from johnhophotography.com';

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n City: $city\n Telephone: $telephone\n Interested: $interested\n Message:\n $message";

if ($_POST['submit']) {              
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
    echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
} else { 
    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
} 
} else if ($_POST['submit']) {
echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
}
?>
```

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Makes following changes:

**First Change:**

In your form tags just add names according to the specified name on a server.

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="email" class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="city" class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="telephone" class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="interested" class="form-control">
<textarea rows="8" name="message" class="form-control"></textarea>
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn-u btn-brd btn-brd-hover btn-u-dark">Send Message</button></p>
```

If you want to receive your form data on a server you have to give it the same name as used it used by your server.

**Second Change:**

Make Following changes in your code:

```
<?php
//Add this two line in your code. It reports you exact problem you are facing in PHP Code.
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

$Name = $_POST['name'];
$Email = $_POST['email'];
$City = $_POST['city'];
$Telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$Interested = $_POST['interested'];
$Message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: Johnhophotography.com'; 
$to = 'cloudsblack84@gmail.com'; 
$subject = 'Message from johnhophotography.com';

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n City: $city\n Telephone: $telephone\n Interested: $interested\n Message:\n $message";

if ($_POST['submit']) {              
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
        echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
    } 
}
else
{
    echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks you Indrasinh Bihola for help ,really appreciated. I had tried the codes from u guys , but cloudsblack84@gmail.com still cannot receive mail form my website ( http://cloudsblack.info/ ) and at the end when I clicked the submit button will go into blank page (http://cloudsblack.info/index.php) . Sorry I am just beginner on web design need to learn a lot from you guys ..wish to get your help again . thanks

Comment: Check my updated answer and if you get any errors please comment it here.

Answer (score 0):

First add a "name" attribute to all input fields and the submit button.

...and then change your PHP to the following:

```
<?php

//get parameters
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$interested = $_POST['interested'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$submit = $_POST['submit'];


if($submit){

    //prepare email
    $from = 'From: Johnhophotography.com'."\r\n"; 
    $to = 'cloudsblack84@gmail.com'; 
    $subject = "Message from johnhophotography.com";
    $body = "".
        "From: ".$name."\n".
        "E-mail: ".$email."\n".
        "City: ".$city."\n".
        "Telephone: ".$telephone."\n".
        "Interested: ".$interested."\n".
        "Message: ".$message."\n";

    //Send email
    if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $from)){
        echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
    }
    else{
        die('<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'); 
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: thanks you ChrisA for help ,really appreciated. I had tried the codes from u guys , but cloudsblack84@gmail.com still cannot receive mail form my website ( http://cloudsblack.info/ ) and at the end when I clicked the submit button will go into blank page (http://cloudsblack.info/index.php) . Sorry I am just beginner on web design need to learn a lot from you guys ..wish to get your help again . thanks

Comment: It looks like the submit button needs a "value" attribute. I tried this on your site and it worked, however it threw a PHP error which you will need to look at.

..so ya, add the following attribute to the submit button:

value="submit"